# How to add simple visitor interaction in joomla 3x?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, plugin, user

I have a download page on my [website](http://www.kbihardware.com). I would like to know who downloaded the content so I need to put this behind user login. Free registration is required, and by providing details like email they can download. So I can have data of users. Right now I am using the built-in register functionality, but the problem is that new users are added in contacts and there are many "contacts" now in a list.

Along with this I need to have all the visitors list in front end so my people can view data directly rather than logging in to the back end checking each of the contacts.

Are there any modules/plugins available for this?

Comment: Have you checked through the Downloads category in the Joomla Extensions Directory at http://extensions.joomla.org/category/directory-a-documentation/downloads? There are quite a few free and paid extensions that will probably do this for you.

Comment: On a side note, please update to Joomla 3.4.5 immediately as your current version is leaving you and your users vulnerable

Comment: Have you looked at Phoca Download?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this options:

File Download Tracker
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/directory-a-documentation/downloads/file-download-tracker

T Download Store
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/e-commerce/paid-downloads/t-download-store

OS Downloads
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/directory-a-documentation/downloads/osdownloads

Answer (score 1):

This is a great extension do exactly you need. I use this extension.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/content-statistics-extended-activity-logs

I hope this helps.

Comment: This looks like advrt. At least post related to question.

Comment: Hi Gaurav. Did you know this component? No isnot advertise. This component has a plugin to monitor and save all actions from user. With this component you can know all downloads, clicks, page views in many others joomla component. If you see this component you will understand. http://www.joomlathat.com/content-statistics If you belive this is advert, please tellme again and i remove the post. Thanks.